# How do you assign the radio transmitter in the "Castle"

Tags: fallout-4

In the castle in Fallout 4 there is a radio transmitter.  It has the red person symbol, when using the workshops, which means a person needs to be assigned to it. However when I attempt to assign a person it shows, "you cannot assign a NPC to this....". I am not sure what it will do if it is assigned, but the question is how is this resource assigned and what character needs to be used? It also begs the question what will assigning a person do for the castle? Thanks for any suggestions or information!

Answer (score 6):

That radio transmitter is for the Radio Freedom broadcast.  It will be automatically assigned by a minutemen when you complete the necessary minutemen quest to retake the castle (taking independence).

The person that takes over (always a male) doesn't seem to be reassignable either.  I've tried to see if I can convert the radio freedom voice into a female minutemen but I haven't seen any way of doing so.

Comment: I believe powering the radio is what causes the NPC to be assigned to it. The OP might not have given power to it yet and therefore is seeing that it's unassigned.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill then that would be a glitch I guess

Comment: When I had it unpowered it only showed the 'Needs 10 elec' symbol, nothing about assigning someone to it. (Finished this mission yesterday).

Answer (score -1):

This is a major glitch. It has been reported. Hopefully next patch will fix. Stuck on last minuteman mission.